# Sum of powers in modulo p field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Prove that for all prime numbers $p$, in the field $\mathbb F_{p}$ consistent with modulo $p$ we have $(a+b)^{p}=a^p+b^p$. My first idea is to use the binomial theorem and show that all but the two outer terms equal zero. Any hints why this might be true?

Comment: You can actually take this further and show that every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a sum of two squares. It's interesting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0<r<p$, we have that $\binom{p}{r}=\frac{p!}{r!(p-r)!}$ is an integer. How many times does $p$ divide the numerator? The denominator? The fraction as a whole?

Comment: I see from your and Kaj's comments that in $\binom{p}{r}$ the numerator is divisible by $p$ while the denominator is not. I somehow still miss how to use this to show the terms cancel out.

Comment: It means that $\binom pr a^rb^{n-r}\equiv 0a^rb^{p-r}\pmod p$.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.  The trick is to show that $p$ divides $\displaystyle  \binom{p}{k}$ for $0 < k < p$.

To do this, recall that $\displaystyle \binom{p}{k} = \frac{p!}{(p-k)!k!}$.  Rearranging, we get $\displaystyle p! = \Big( (p-k)!k! \Big) \binom{p}{k}$. Notice that $p$ divides the LHS of this equation, so it must also divide the RHS...